# To show that Bayes classifier has best error rate

Tags: probability, self-study, classification, bayesian, dataset

Show that the bayes classifier will achieve the best error rate,
defined as:

$$
E(f) = \int \int \mathbb{I}(y = f(x)) \cdot p(x, y) dxdy
$$

where $$f(x)$$ is the classifier, and $$p(x, y)$$ is the intrinsic data distribution.

I just want to get some help as to how to proceed.

Comment: You probably need to add the self-study tag to this, and read the wiki for said tag.  Your question is also not well posed, as you do not define "error rate", and the successful resolution of your query almost certainly depends on the correct interpretation of that term (there are many ways to define "error rate").

Comment: The definition of error rate is given in the question

Comment: Ahh, I read incorrectly, my humble apologies - I am sorry for my poor reading comprehension.  Please add the self-study tag none-the-less.

Comment: How is $l$ defined, in the integral?

Comment: What do u mean by _l_ ?

Comment: Ah I take it that is an indicator function.  So this "error rate" is something we want to maximize, weirdly enough, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

If by Bayes classifier you mean a maximum *a posteriori* probability (MAP or MAPP) decision rule, then for *discrete* random variables, an intuitive explanation can be found *[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/278187/6633).*  More generally, the fact that the minimum probability of error decision rule is the one that decides that $H_i$ is the true hypothesis if $$\pi_if_i(x) > \pi_{1-i}f_{1-i}(x),$$ is easily derived (see, e.g. *[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129810/6633)* for details). The rule above can also be expressed as 
$$L(x) = \frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)} ~~\begin{array}{c}H_1\\ \gtrless\\H_0\end{array}~~\frac{\pi_0}{\pi_1}$$
which can be recognized as a likelihood ratio test with the Bayesian threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be the Bayes classifier and let $g$ be another classifier.  Note that for any $x$,

$$
\int \mathbb{I}[y=f(x)]\cdot p(y|x)dy = p(f(x)|x) \geq p(g(x)|x) = \int \mathbb{I}[y=g(x)]\cdot p(y|x)dy,
$$
by the definition of $f$.  Once we see that
$$
E(f) = \int p(f(x)|x) \cdot p(x) dx,
$$
we are done.